# Magnets falling through solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm unsure about something in electromagnetism....When a bar magnet falls through a solenoid, does it travel at a constant velocity due to the opposing force caused due to Lenz's Law? Or does the gravitational acceleration not affected by this?

Answer (score 2):

Changing magnetic field caused by falling magnet induces current in the solenoid such that the magnetic field caused by induced current is opposite to magnetic field that induces a current (Lenz's Law). The induced current is proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic field so, the faster the magnet is going, the more current it induces and therefore the stronger magnetic field is induced that opposes the motion of the magnet.

If there is no sources of current in the solenoid other than the falling magnet, the force on the magnet will get stronger and stronger until gravity cancels it out and after that, magnet will fall with constant velocity.

Comment: I am assuming you have solenoid of infinite length and that it is oriented in the vertical direction so that force of gravity is collinear with the force of induced current.

Comment: Here is a brief experiment demonstrating what is stated in this answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7tIi71-AjA

Comment: But how does the infinite length affect the answer please explain.